# PHP - Create a list of times, with those times where an event is scheduled are given a different class

Tags: php, css, web-applications

I would like to create a list of times, in table form, from 9am to 9pm, in 30-minute intervals.  For each of those intervals where I have an event scheduled, I'd like the cell to be red, and for those where the room is free, I'd like them to be green.

So far, I've only been able to list the times where the room is in use, but I need to fill in with the available times in green boxes.  Here's my code so far.  :

```
foreach ($events[$event_day] as $event) {

    $meetstatus = $event['status'];
    $start = $event['time1'];
    $end = $event['time2'];

    $tStart = strtotime($start);
    $tEnd = strtotime($end);
    $tNow = $tStart;
    if ($event['roomchoice'] == 'Meeting Room') {
        while ($tNow <= $tEnd) {
            $time = date("H:iA", $tNow) . "\n";
            $calendar .= '<tr><td class="meeting-' . $meetstatus . '">' . $time . '</td></tr>';
            $tNow = strtotime('+30 minutes', $tNow);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ever heard of Cron? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

Comment: `if($meetstatus == 'busy'){//red} else {//green}`

Comment: if $meetstatus has the correct value there should not be a problem. you are using the css classname to visually distinguish the cases, likely the value of $event['status'] is not as you expect when the room is free. and you could move the $meetstatus... $tNow = $tStart; block into the if block, no reason to run code that will not do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood that you have potentially more intervals than events. If this holds true your outer loop needs to go for intervals rather than events:

```
$strintervalstarts=array('9:00','9:30',...)
foreach ($strintervalstarts as $strintervalstart) {
  $intervalstart=strtotime($strintervalstart);
  $intervalend=...
```

... need to be replaced by your code

I believe, it is easy from there. However some more tips, that you may need:

- http://php.net/manual/de/function.date-add.php (date, maketime to compute the intervalend)
- you need to define for yourself if your color coding is about 'this event is in an interval completely' OR 'the event touches the interval, but exceeds it (partial overlap)'
- > according to your decision you need an if that puts $tStart in relation to $intervalstart and $tEnd in relation to $intervalend

Comment: Making the outer loop go through the times and using a foreach loop inside it to check for matching times was exactly the tip I needed to get it working.